# Thread Constructor Initialization C++

Tags: c++, concurrency

I have been attempting to write a simple program to experiment with vectors of threads. I am trying to create a thread at the moment, but I am finding that I am running into an error that my constructor is not initializing properly, with the error that there is no matching constructor for std::thread matching the argument list. Here is what I have done:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int sum = 0; 
void thread_sum (auto it, auto it2, auto init) {
  sum = std::accumulate(it, it2, init);
}

int main() {
  // * Non Multi-Threaded
  // We're going to sum up a bunch of numbers.
  std::vector<int> toBeSummed;
  for (int i = 0; i < 30000; ++i) {
    toBeSummed.push_back(1);
  }
  // Initialize a sum variable
  long sum = std::accumulate(toBeSummed.begin(), toBeSummed.end(), 0);

  std::cout << "The sum was " << sum << std::endl; 
  // * Multi Threaded
  // Create threads
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  std::thread t1(&thread_sum, toBeSummed.begin(), toBeSummed.end(), 0);
  std::thread t2(&thread_sum, toBeSummed.begin(), toBeSummed.end(), 0);
  threads.push_back(std::move(t1));
  threads.push_back(std::move(t2));
  return 0; 
}
```

The line that messes up is the following:

```cpp
  auto t1 =
      std::thread {std::accumulate, std::ref(toBeSummed.begin()),
```

It is an issue with the constructor. I have tried different combinations of std::ref, std::function, and other wrappers, and tried making my own function lambda object as a wrapper for accumulate.

Here is some additional information:

The error message is : atomics.cpp:28:7: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'

Moreover, when hovering over the constructor, it tells me that the first parameter is of <unknown_type>.

Other attempts I have tried:

- Using references instead of regular value parameters
- Using `std::bind`
- Using `std::function`
- Declaring the function in a variable and passing that as my first parameter to the constructor
- Compiling with different flags, like `std=c++2a`

**EDIT**:

1. I will leave the original issue as a means for others to learn from my mistakes. As the answer I accept will show, this is due to my excessive usage of auto. I had read a C++ book that basically said "always use auto, it's much more readable! Like Python and dynamic typing, but with the performance of C++," yet clearly this cannot always be done. The `using` keyword provides the readability while still the safety. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: `std::thread t1(, toBeSummed.begin(), toBeSummed.end(), 0);` looks broken. It's missing the first argument.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the result of the accumulate function, you might prefer [async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) or [packaged_task](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) which can give you a future with the result.

Comment: There are some undefined behaviour in your thread code, you don't join the threads after starting them, .join them before exiting or if you have c++20's jthread available use that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems you're encountering are because `std::accumulate` is an overloaded function template, so the compiler doesn't know what specific function type to treat it as when passed as an argument to the thread constructor. Similar problems arise with your `thread_sum` function because of the `auto` parameters.

You can choose a specific overload/instantiation of `std::accumulate` as follows:

```
  std::thread t2(
      (int(*)(decltype(toBeSummed.begin()), decltype(toBeSummed.end()), int))std::accumulate,
       toBeSummed.begin(), toBeSummed.end(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your excessive use of `auto`.  You can fix it by changing this one line:

```
void thread_sum (auto it, auto it2, auto init) {
```

To this:

```
using Iter = std::vector<int>::const_iterator;
void thread_sum (Iter it, Iter it2, int init) {
```